# Proof union of two disjoint perfect matchings in a bipartite graph is covering all vertices of G with disjoint cycles

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am trying to prove that the union of two disjoint perfect matchings in a bipartite graph is covering all vertices of G with disjoint cycles.

I would appreciate if anyone knew the proof or had ideas about it

Answer (score 1):

Let $(V_1,V_2)$ be the bipartition sets, $M_1$, $M_2$ the two matchings, and $G'$ the graph with vertex set $V_1\cup V_2$ and edge set $M_1\cup M_2$. Since $G$ is bipartite, each edge in a matching is incident on a vertex $u\in V_1$ and a vertex in $V_2$, so $|M_1|\leqslant|V_1|,|V_2|$. But $M_1$ is a perfect matching, so $|M_1|\geqslant|V_1|,|V_2|$, and so $|M_1|=|V_1|=|V_2|$ (and similarly $|M_2|=|M_1|$).

Since $M_1\cap M_2=\varnothing$, each vertex in $u\in G'$ is incident with an edge $uv\in M_1$ and some $uw\in M_2$. It follows that $G'$ is $2$-regular, and so is the union of disjoint cycles.

Comment: What is the first paragraph for? Doesn't the second paragraph do the job all by itself? And what does "bipartite" have to do with it? The union of two disjoint perfect matchings in any graph is going to be a $2$-regular subgraph, isn't it?